# Append the Index to the Link

Tags: jquery

I need assistance with adding the index of each link to itself. This solution adds the index to the title on a click, but I'd like to its index to already be applied without having to click or hover for example.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var count = $(this).index('a');
    $(this).attr("title",'link '+count);
return false;
});
```

I'm looking for the output to be like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="1">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.Amazon.com" title="2">Amazon</a>
<a href="http://www.Apple.com" title="3">Apple</a>
<a href="http://www.Microsoft.com" title="4">Microsoft</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hxvppm3c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxvppm3c/2/

```
$("a").each(
    function() {
        var count = $(this).index('a');
        $(this).attr("title",'link '+count);
    }
);
```

The issue was returning false in a jquery `each` breaks out of the loop. Just remove the `return false`.

Comment: Yeah, I was. Thanks for that. Geez. :)